# Kubernetes run on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, spring-cloud

I've been struggling with configuring Kubernetes for many hours and I don't know how to move it forward.

What I did :

1. I created few services using spring cloud
2. I created docker images for each service
3. I pushed those images to docker hub
4. I launched AWS by running

   ```
   export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws; wget -q -O - https://get.k8s.io | bash
   ```

Command `kubectl cluster-info` shows that it actually works.

5. I created Kubernetes pods for each service. Command `kubectl get pods`
   shows that all pods have status running.

The problem is that when I log to my AWS account I don't see any running instance, although I can see kubernetes-staging created in my S3 bucket.

My goal is to actually access my service , not on localhost. How can I do it ?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right region? You might also want to consider using `kops` to bring clusters up.

Comment: Would be interesting to learn whether you have further details or whether you found a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see instances of course - as @kichik mentioned check whether your AWS console is using the same region as the deployment scripts.

To use your services/applications the next step is to expose them to the public with Kubernetes services as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose-intro/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/)